# How to require validation in python?

Tags: python

How to make these require validation in Python?
I want it to work as such: If I submit either an empty title / empty content - Python will not approve the creation of the article.

Right now it's only using the "required" attribute in HTML, which can easily be disabled / does not work in all browsers.

```
@route('/edit/<pagename>')
def edit_article(pagename):
    
    articles=read_articles_from_file()
    for article in articles:
        if article['title'] == pagename:
            titel = article
        
    
    return template("editarticle", article = titel)
```

```
        <main>
            <a href="/"><h1>BasicWiki</h1></a>
            <h2>Redigerar {{article['title']}}</h2>
            <form action="/update" method="POST">
                <label for="article">Titel (ersätt artikel genom att använda samma titel)</label>
                <input type="text" id="article" name="title" value="{{article['title']}}" required>
                <label for="content">Artikel Text (HTML tillåtet)</label>
                <input type="text" id="content" name="content" value="{{article['content']}}" required>
                <input type="submit" value="Skicka">
            </form>



        </main>
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you are using Flask, if so [Form Validation with WTForms](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/wtforms/) might be helpful

Comment: I'm using Bottle so I don't know if this applies @AbdulAzizBarkat

Comment: Never used bottle but, but [this](https://bottle-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html#module-bottle_utils.form.forms) looks somewhat promising